# Query formula to replace filter

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets filter formula that I need to replace with something, I was thinking QUERY, but I can't seem to make that work?

**=FILTER(Food!$B:$K,Food!$A:$A=true,TODAY()>=Food!$C:$C,(Food!$D:$D-TODAY())<=14,NOT(ISBLANK(Food!$C:$C)),NOT(ISBLANK((Food!$D:$D-TODAY()))))**

I need to IMPORTRANGE the filtered results and they lose their table formatting.  I got QUERY working but with fixed dates.  I have tried numerous combinations and can't seem to nail down the syntax.

Here is a copy of the sheet and the formula I need help with is in the Specials tab, A2.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16bAAI-A_EMsy1noj8U-fhIuT4XTbfgOJuxvzi_0hYhk/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you!

Comment: Is this a problem before or after importrange? When you use importrange you import only values - never any formatting.

Comment: It's before the IMPORTRANGE sheet.  This sheet in the above question is a sheet for restaurants to report their latest specials and then there is another sheet which aggregates the data and it's there where the IMPORTRANGE happens.

Here is a link to a drawing.  https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1RODufJwe2gcOB8TD0Wxe2WMisnvPoysr_o3MoL5qLrg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Does this formula do what you want?

```
=QUERY(Food!$A:$K,"select * 
  where A=TRUE 
    and (C > date '2000-01-01' and C <  date '" & TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd") & "') 
    and (D > date '2000-01-01' and D <= date '" & TEXT(TODAY()+14,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "') ",0)
```

The first date test for C and D is to ensure they aren't blank.  Using `C <> ''`  or `C <> 0` didn't work, I guess since it is a date field.

**UPDATE**

My mistake - I left out some of the logic I'd included at first.
Try this:

```
=QUERY(Food!$A:$K,"select B,C,D,E 
  where A=TRUE 
    and (C > date '2000-01-01' and  C <= date '" & TEXT(TODAY(),   "yyyy-mm-dd") & "') 
    and (D > date '2000-01-01' and (D >= date '" & TEXT(TODAY(),   "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'
                               and  D <= date '" & TEXT(TODAY()+14,"yyyy-mm-dd") & "')) ",0)
```

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to work?  I get two out of the four entries that meet the intended conditions.

You can find this example on the sheet link in the original question on the Specials tab, A2.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by wrapping the FILTER in a QUERY.  I had to improve the logic for an End Date >=TODAY() but it worked the way I need after the additional argument.

```
=QUERY(FILTER(Food!$B:$K,
Food!$A:$A=true,
TODAY()>=Food!$C:$C,
(Food!$D:$D>=TODAY()),
(Food!$D:$D-TODAY())<=14,
NOT(ISBLANK(Food!$C:$C)),
NOT(ISBLANK((Food!$D:$D-TODAY())))))
```

I'm happy to learn that I can QUERY(FILTER( then IMPORTRANGE the results properly.

Thanks for the interest.

Comment: I don't believe that your QUERY is adding anything.  It just returns all of the rows that the FILTER  is already returning.  Remove the query and you still get the same results...

Comment: I was getting specials that were expired because the original logic didn't have a floor of greater than or equal to today.  The extra argument sets a floor of today or great for the end date.  (Food!$D:$D>=TODAY()),